# What is the difference between these 2 maven plugins?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, maven-failsafe-plugin

What is the difference between maven plugins?

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>failsafe-maven-plugin</artifactId>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
```

Comment: They are the same; the mojo plugin was at one point in time moved to Maven itself to become a "standard" plugin. So the maven one is newer. http://mojo.codehaus.org/plugins.html

Comment: @Gimby That should be an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, this is the same plugin which moved from `org.codehaus.mojo` to  `org.apache.maven.plugins`. Here is the [message](https://markmail.org/message/s37fypzfwww3mpbe) on the mailing list org.codehaus.mojo.dev which ask to vote for the retirement of the old version (the vote was accepted at the unanimity):

> Subject:   [mojo-dev] [VOTE] Retire failsafe-maven-plugin  permalink
>
> From:  Stephen Connolly (step...@gmail.com)
>
> Date:  Jan 17, 2010 3:07:01 am
>
> List:  org.codehaus.mojo.dev
>
> I have moved failsafe-maven-plugin to maven-failsafe-plugin @ apache.
>
> This vote is to retire the failsafe-maven-plugin.
>
> +1: I agree it's pointless having the two it will only confuse people
>
> 0: meh, I don't care
>
> -1: Me I object and I will take care of maintaining
>   failsafe-maven-plugin because that's the kind of person I am.
>
> If the vote passes I will replace the failsafe-maven-plugin site with
>   a redirect to the maven-failsafe-plugin
>   (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin)
>
> I am not sure if we need to deploy a relocation pom, somebody with
>   more knowledge of the plugin resolution code could advise whether the
>   relocation is processed for plugins...
>
> In any case, if the vote passes I will take that as approval to do
>   what is necessary to retire the failsafe-maven-plugin
>
> Stephen
>
> P.S. My vote is +1